# convert partition to vhd windows API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, vhd

I am trying to code a tool like disk2vhd. I'm using the VHD windows api:

[Virtual Disk Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323699.aspx)

[The Virtual Disk API In Windows 7](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569754.aspx)

[Demo various VHD API usage (CppVhdAPI)](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowshardware/cppvhdapi-4412d182)

I created a vhd file and created a partition in it, but I don't know how to convert a Windows partition to vhd like disk2vhd creates a vhd using `CreateVirtualDisk()`.

I've tried to copy all items from that partition to my vhd but it does not work.

Please show me how to do that.

Comment: You've already found some good sources of information. Why don't you use them? When you get stuck, show us the code you have and then ask a specific question about that code.

Comment: can you teach (show) me solution to do that @David

Comment: Why did you revert my question edit and make the question formatting worse? Was that an accident?

Comment: Hi @Devid
i was use it, but i can't find that (partition to vhd)on windows api
create vhd windows api is : CreateVirtualDisk
open vhd: OpenVirtualDisk

Comment: Never mind. I don't think I can help you if our communication is on this level. It won't work if the communication only goes in one direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should do the following:

1. Load hard disk's information,
2. load disk partition,
3. create a file vhd,
4. copy partition to vhd.